# Singularity of Generating Function

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, generating-functions

Given

$E' = (E^2 + E - x)/2xE$ 
$xF = E^3 E' + 2xE^3 E'' + E^2 - x^2$

where 
$E = \sum_{n > 0}{e_n x^n}$ 
with $e_n = (n-1) \sum^{n-1}_{i = 1}{e_i e_{n-i}}$ for $n > 1$ and $e_1 = 1$

I am interested in finding the singularity of $F$ with smallest modulus, when interpreting $F$ as a function in the complex plane.

I just started studying analytic combinatorics by my self but my calculus knowledge is a bit rusty, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a pointer: [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Comment: Lagrange reversion, contour integration, and analysis of poles seem very much on the analytic side to me... and *gfology* explains them all. Nevermind. The other classic book in this area is *Analytic combinatorics*, by Flajolet and Sedgewick.

Comment: My last comment answered a comment by @Andy, now deleted. // On another note, there is a problem with the recursive relation on the coefficients $e_n$ since the only solution of the current one seems to be $e_n=0$ for every $n$.

Comment: @Didier Thank you. I deleted my comment because I was not precise, there is a part of analytical comb. in Wilfs book. Analytic combinatorics, is the book I started studying.

Comment: @Didier $e_n$: I made a mistake in the sum, the highest index is now changed to be $n-1$ not $n$

Comment: Which does not save your recursion.

Comment: Hm, I don't see any problem for n > 1 and $e_1 = 1$

Comment: Except that $e_n=(n-1)$times something yields $e_1=0$.

Comment: Ok I clarified it

Comment: A trivial observation: what you want is the dominant singularity of $xF$ instead of $F$ (because it's $0$), but it's ok since you'll get the asymptotics for $[x^n]F$ shifted by one. The dominant singularity of $xF$ is the singularity with smallest radius of $E$, $E'$ or $E''$.
Using the recurrence we should be able to give a closed form for $E$.

Comment: $E$ in OEIS: http://oeis.org/A000699

Comment: Another observation: the dominant singularity of $x^kF$ is the one of $E$, because of the differential equation for $E'$ (and also we have $E'' = (xE + x^2 - E^3 - E^4)/(4x^2 E^3)$). (I added a constant $k$ to get rid of the $x^k$ in the denominator).

Answer (score 1):

The relevant [OEIS page](http://oeis.org/A000699), mentioned by @Diego in the comments, links to *Analytic Combinatorics of Chord Diagrams* by P. Flajolet and M. Noy, which refers to P.R. Stein and C.J. Everett, *On a Class of Linked Diagrams II. Asymptotics*, Discrete Mathematics 21 1978, 309-318, to assert that
$$
e_n\sim\frac1{\mathrm e}\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}.
$$
Stirling's approximation yields
$$
e_n\sim\frac{\sqrt2}{\mathrm e}\left(\frac{2n}{\mathrm e}\right)^n,
$$
hence the radius of convergence of the series $E(x)=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}e_nx^n$ is zero. The same is true for $F(x)$.